# Counting words in files

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, file

I made a simple program for my study that calculates words in a text files and prints every word and its repeated times in the files.

How can I improve this code?

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <exception>

typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, std::size_t> Words;

Words wordsInFile(const std::string& fileName)
{
    std::ifstream file(fileName);
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        throw "Can't open the file" + fileName;
    }

    Words loadFromFile;


    for (std::string word; file >> word;)
    {
        ++loadFromFile[word];
    }

    return loadFromFile;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::future<Words>> futures;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) 
    {
        futures.push_back(std::async([=] { return wordsInFile(argv[i]); }));
    }

    Words words;

    for (auto& i : futures) 
    {
        const auto results = i.get();

        for (const auto& j : results) 
        {
            words[j.first] = j.second;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Word\tRepeated Times\n-------------------------\n";
    for (const auto& i : words)
        std::cout << i.first << "\t\t" << i.second << '\n';
}
```

test.txt

> ```
> File system is huge subject need more work out. file is plain text file
> This is some junk words. simple program for words counting in text file. 1 2 3
> 2 2 2 2
> @ % & ^ *
> all so good
> this test text file
> ```

Output:

> ```
> Word    Repeated Times
> -------------------------
> File            1
> out.            1
> 1               1
> system          1
> 2               5
> is              3
> need            1
> huge            1
> subject         1
> work            1
> more            1
> %               1
> file            3
> plain           1
> text            3
> This            1
> some            1
> junk            1
> program         1
> words.          1
> simple          1
> for             1
> words           1
> counting                1
> in              1
> file.           1
> so              1
> 3               1
> @               1
> &               1
> ^               1
> this            1
> *               1
> all             1
> good            1
> test            1
> ```

Comment: why are you using futures?

Comment: If I get this right, you are counting the lines of each file in a separate task/tread (with `async`), correct? Interesting idea to optimize batch processing of several files.

Comment: BTW, the title should be either "Counting words in *a file*" (singular) or "Counting words *in files*" (plural). `;)`

Comment: @sp2danny .. you can use `std::thread` and `std::mutex` but `std::future` and `std::async` are type-safe buildin and easy to implement them in your code like i did

Comment: @glampert .. exactly except that it stores each element from `std::unordered_map` that has all words which is return value from `wordsInFile()` function as shown above and assign `by copy` to a new `std::unordered_map`. yes, it can handle many files as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see some things that may help you improve your code.

### Simplify your code

You don't need a lambda at all.  Use this instead:

```
    futures.push_back(std::async(wordsInFile,argv[i]));
```

Also, instead of `if (!file.is_open())` use the more idiomatic `if (!file)`.

### Fix the counting

If we have two files which both contain the word `fox` exactly once then I would expect the result of this program to print `fox   2` but in fact, it would falsely claim a count of `1`.  The problem is this line:

```
words[j.first] = j.second;
```

This overwrites the count instead of accumulating it.  This is what you need instead:

```
words[j.first] += j.second;
```

### Use `reserve` to prevent reallocations

This code already knows how many `futures` are going to be created.  The code can be made a little more efficient by using this:

```
futures.reserve(argc-1);
```

With large numbers of files, this eliminates the re-allocation that would be required by dynamically resizing the `vector`.

### Check for exceptions

If any of the file names can't be read.  That is, if it can be opened but not read, as with a directory under Linux, this code will throw an error that isn't caught and so therefore results in a crash.  Since `future::get()` will throw any error that was stored, it's that part of the code that should check for exceptions.  One alternative would be this:

```
    Words results;
    try {
        results = i.get();
    }
    catch(std::exception &err)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: " << err.what() << '\n';
    }
    catch(std::string &err)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: " << err << '\n';
    }
    for (const auto& j : results) 
    {
        words[j.first] += j.second;
    }
```

Note that this will simply skip the offending file name but continue to process the rest.

### Measure your results

Create a non-parallel version of this code and compare the timing to see if it's faster or slower than this version.  I have found that it's often true that the overhead of the implicit (as in `async`) or explicit (as in `thread`) thread creation swamps the savings in time by making things parallel.  The only way to know for sure is to time it.

Comment: i don't know why VC++ fail to compile without using lambda object in vector. i haven't test it yet GCC

Comment: bind works as well,`futures.push_back(std::async(std::bind(wordsInFile, argv[i])));` in VC++

Comment: If VC++ is using C++14 version of that feature, you might try an explicit policy:  `std::async(std::launch::async, wordsInFile, argv[i])`. Also handy to check parallel vs. serial timing; simply change the policy to `std::launch::deferred` and you have a serial implementation.